# i don't know why there is an error in my for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

i dont understand why there is an error(The method findNodeByNode(ITreeNode<>) is undefined for the type NODETYPE) in my for loop. A college has exactly the same code, but he has no errors?
Please help me

```
public class GenericTreeNode<NODETYPE> extends Object implements ITreeNode<NODETYPE> {
NODETYPE nodeValue;
String label;
private LinkedList<NODETYPE> children;

public GenericTreeNode(String label, NODETYPE value)
{
    this.label=label;
    this.nodeValue=value;
    children= new LinkedList<NODETYPE>();
}
public boolean checkNodeByValue(NODETYPE value) {

    if(this.nodeValue.equals(value))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

public ITreeNode<NODETYPE> findNodeByValue(NODETYPE searchValue) {


    if(this.checkNodeByValue(searchValue))
    {
        return this;
    }

    if(this.isLeaf())
    {
        return null;
    }

    long length = this.children.size();
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        this.children.get(i)).findNodeByValue( searchValue);
    }


    return null;
}
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have two consecutive parentheses:

```
      get(i))
```

Change the sentence by:

```
    this.children.get(i).findNodeByValue( searchValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

findNodeByValue(...) belongs to the class GenericTreeNode<NODETYPE>, but you are calling it on an instance of NODETYPE in your LinkedList<NODETYPE>. You can only call it on an instance of GenericTreeNode<NODETYPE> (or just call it if doing it on this instance of the class)